# If a website is constantly changing, can it be implemented with next.js?

Tags: next.js, upload, host

I hope you are doing well
I want to make a book site with next.js. My site needs to be updated and add products every day. I want to know now if it is appropriate to make this site with next.js?

Now, my website is complete and I ran it with next.js, my website is with node.js, and now every product that I add, I have to go and get a build from the next.js project and upload it to the host, and is this a difficult job? If anyone has a better way, I would be grateful if they could help

Comment: This is kind of confusing and will likely get closed without more information.  The first question that comes to mind is, what exactly do you mean by, "every product that I add, I have to go and get a build from the next.js project and upload it to the host" ?  How are you adding these products exactly?  It kind of sounds like you are just manually writing the HTML for every new product as opposed to adding them into a DB or something?

Comment: So you aren't storing products in a DB anywhere, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [Showcase](https://nextjs.org/showcase#e-commerce) on next.js official website. It's powerful enough to make any kind of dynamic website. You need to use `getServerSideProps` with the database of your choice. If you are using Static HTML Export you have to rebuild and upload it again whenever you make any changes.

There's also a lot of options to automate next.js deployment, Best option for your use case is to use services like [Digital Ocean App Platform](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-nextjs-deploy) so whenever you push some changes to git repo it automatically rebuild and update your site with fresh content.